# How to make platform specific code in Quasar project?

Tags: vue.js, cordova, vuejs2, amazon-cognito, quasar-framework

I'm doin a **Quasar** project.

For the **OAuth**, in **SPA**, I have to use “**OAuth 2.0 Client ID**” of type “**Web application**” but when I build an **Android App** with **Cordova**, I must use “**OAuth 2.0 Client ID**” of type “**Android**”

How do you manage to have platform specific code?